# How to set up start date in time series in with hourly data

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, cran, hour

I have a time series that is hourly electricity load in Ireland. This is the data frame:

```
    > head(load2)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  datetime            fecha       hora load_MWH
  <dttm>              <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01     0     7594
2 2018-01-01 01:00:00 2018-01-01     1     7091
3 2018-01-01 02:00:00 2018-01-01     2     6652
4 2018-01-01 03:00:00 2018-01-01     3     6308
5 2018-01-01 04:00:00 2018-01-01     4     5972
6 2018-01-01 05:00:00 2018-01-01     5     5810
```

I want to create a Time Series object with daily seasonality and start date 2018-01-01 00:00:00 with one year worth of data - however, I am unable to get right the date axis. I tried the following:

```
my_ts = ts(load2[,4], frequency = 24, start= c(as.numeric(as.Date("2018-01-01")),1))
```

which seems to work:

```
head(my_ts)
Time Series:
Start = c(17532, 1) 
End = c(17532, 6) 
Frequency = 24 
     load_MWH
[1,]     7594
[2,]     7091
[3,]     6652
[4,]     6308
[5,]     5972
[6,]     5810
```

But the time axis of the time series is a number (i.e number of seconds since origin in 1970-01-01) but not a date format and therefore I can not make any operation with dates and autoplot shows the number but not the month / year:

```
> autoplot(energyireland2018_ts2[,1]) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b/%d")
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the
existing scale.
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Similarly, I cannot use any of the forecast package functions that manipulate dates.

So the question is: **how can I convert the time axis of this time series into a Date object?** (still using the forecast package). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `ts` class and the **forecast** package do not work well with hourly data. I suggest you use the newer `tsibble` class, for which there is an `autoplot` function in the **feasts** package and forecasting functions in the **fable** package. Here is an example using half-hourly electricity demand data.

```r
library(feasts)
library(tsibbledata)

vic_elec
#> # A tsibble: 52,608 x 5 [30m] <Australia/Melbourne>
#>    Time                Demand Temperature Date       Holiday
#>    <dttm>               <dbl>       <dbl> <date>     <lgl>  
#>  1 2012-01-01 00:00:00  4383.        21.4 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  2 2012-01-01 00:30:00  4263.        21.0 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  3 2012-01-01 01:00:00  4049.        20.7 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  4 2012-01-01 01:30:00  3878.        20.6 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  5 2012-01-01 02:00:00  4036.        20.4 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  6 2012-01-01 02:30:00  3866.        20.2 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  7 2012-01-01 03:00:00  3694.        20.1 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  8 2012-01-01 03:30:00  3562.        19.6 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#>  9 2012-01-01 04:00:00  3433.        19.1 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#> 10 2012-01-01 04:30:00  3359.        19.0 2012-01-01 TRUE   
#> # … with 52,598 more rows

autoplot(vic_elec, Demand)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For information about the packages that handle these objects, see http://tidyverts.org.

For a textbook introduction to forecasting models and associated syntax, see http://OTexts.com/fpp3

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was hoping to use forecast package after some investment on it and also because it is largely used in the textbook you mention but I will check our the packages you recommend!

Comment: http://otexts.com/fpp2 uses the forecast package. http://otexts.com/fpp3 uses the fable package.

Comment: I would like to add that the book Forecasting: Principles and Practice, by prof. @RobHyndman, is a great resource for learning about the modern time series theory, in a very practical and hands on way.